# Augment a class with new properties exported with export = MyClass

Tags: typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable, typescript-declarations

I have written a plugin [jspdf-autotable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) for [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). Jspdf exports a class `jsPDF` which I want to augment with a new `autoTable` method once the user imports my plugin. Reading the module augmentation section in [Declaration Merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) it seems the following should work.

```
// Existing index.d.ts for jspdf
// https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jspdf/index.d.ts
declare module 'jspdf' {
  class jsPDF {
    constructor(orientation?: any);

    setPage(n:number):jsPDF;
    save(filename:string):jsPDF;
    // ...
  }

  namespace jsPDF {}

  export = jsPDF;
}

// Proposed index.d.ts for the plugin jspdf-autotable
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

declare module 'jspdf' {
  export function staticMethod(); // Test

  interface jsPDF {
    autoTable(): jsPDF;
  }
}

// Usage
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';

jsPDF.staticMethod() // This works
let doc = new jsPDF();
doc.autoTable(); // This gives error: Property 'autoTable' does not exist on type
doc.save('table.pdf');
```

However the autoTable method is not found. Note that the static method works for some reason though. Is there a way to make this work without changing the jspdf declarations? If not, how can I update the jspdf declarations for allowing plugins like this (it is [officially supported](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/3b6bb86f6490df6fddbc8155b6460c38c26c0ed0/examples/jspdf.PLUGINTEMPLATE.js))?

Comment: I don't have deeply investigate but what is written [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#disallowed-merges) can be the problem?

Comment: That seems to be about not being able to merge two classes? Here I want to add a method to a class which should be possible? :/